# How do I safely sell a Wii with VC games on it?

Tags: nintendo-wii, virtual-console

I want to sell my Wii with the VC games included, but am afraid there might be some personal info on the system somewhere.

If I delete my shop account & format the system memory, will the next owner be able to re-download the games free?

If I leave the VC games on there, is there any reason to worry? I looked at my account activity and saw the last 4 of my CC#. Can anything be done with that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't wipe your Wii without wiping the VC games, and they can't download them without having full access to your Wii Shop account and any credit card information it stores.

You can't sell a Wii with VC installed without handing the buyer considerable amounts of personal and financial information.

It's also, aside from that, against the licensing of VC content to resell it: it's explicitly non-transferable when you buy it. As a consequence, it will come as no surprise that Nintendo has set up the system such that you can't clear personal info off a Wii in preparation for reselling it without also wiping the Wii Shop downloads.

Comment: Dang was afraid of that :( Glad I only got a few games. Better safe than sorry!

Comment: @gpryatel Yeah, I'm distinctly uncomfortable buying games that can just go "poof" like that. I bought a few VC games myself, but the price/permanence ratio was just too much to swallow.

Comment: One thing: I'm pretty sure the Wii Shop Channel doesn't even have an option to store credit card information. The eShop (or at least some versions of it) does have this feature, but it is optional.